# Set/Fake/Mock window.external in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mocking, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a website that uses window.external (that will later run in a WPF WebBrowser control).

However, all window.external methods are undefined although I tried:

```
window.external = {
    SetDragText: function() {},
    ShowFileDialog: function() { 
        onFileOpenCompleted(JSON.stringify(["D:\Temp\test.pdf"])) 
    },
    OpenPdfViewer: function() {},
};
```

Is there a way to override `window.external` in Chrome debug/Dev Tools?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you need to type the function without the brackets to get the definition, otherwise you are calling it, which returns undefined since you don't return anything

```js
window.external = {
    SetDragText: function() {},
    ShowFileDialog: function() { 
        onFileOpenCompleted(JSON.stringify(["D:\Temp\test.pdf"])) 
    },
    OpenPdfViewer: function() {},
};
$("#result").text("Actual function definition: " + String(window.external.SetDragText));
$("#result2").text(String("Function call result: " + window.external.SetDragText()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="result"></span>
</br>
<span id="result2"></span>
```

Comment: Hmm I have just checked again. It works for me now. However sometimes later, `window.external` is back to External object again. I guess somehow I got another `window` context or `external` object.

Comment: Sorry found the problem. It's Chrome's new debug override feature problem. My overridden code was not run consistently.